# Executing an external program when forking is not advisable

Tags: c, linux, posix

I have this a big server software that can hog 4-8GB of memory.

This makes fork-exec cumbersome, as the fork itself can take significant time, plus the default behavior seems to be that fork will fail unless there is enough memory for a copy of the entire resident memory.

Since this is starting to show as the hottest spot (60% of time spent in fork) when profiling I need to address it.

What would be the easiest way to avoid fork-exec routine?

Comment: You didn't specify the OS, but on Linux fork() uses copy-on-write so I don't anticipate performance issue

Comment: If you want to avoid copying the parent memory maybe `vfork` can help .

Comment: It is hard to believe that 60% of your time is spent in fork. How many forks are you doing per second?

Comment: @Marian Hard to say. There could be upto 10k forks per second in peaks if the the events could be processed that fast.

Comment: Can you post the actual code you have that performs the fork & exec? As others are commenting, the behavior you are seeing is not what I would expect. Maybe there is another explanation

Comment: @Let_Me_Be 10,000 forks *per second?!* Your architecture sounds quite broken.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to explain what external commands you are really running, and how often you start them (10 times per second, or 5000 times per second)....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically cannot avoid [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) (or the equivalent [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) syscall..., or the obsolete `vfork` which I don't recommend using) + [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) to start an external command (à la [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html), or à la [posix_spawn](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_spawn.html)) on Linux and (probably) MacOSX and most other Unix or POSIX systems.

What makes you think that it is becoming an issue? And 8GB process virtual address space is not a big deal today (at least on machines with 8Gbytes, or 16Gbytes RAM, like my desktop has). You don't practically need twice as much RAM (but you do need swap space) thanks to the lazy [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) techniques used by all recent Unixes & Linux.

Perhaps you might believe that swap space could be an issue. On Linux, you could add swap space, perhaps by swapping on a file; just run as root:

```
 dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/tmp/myswap bs=1M count=32768
 mkswap /var/tmp/myswap
 swapon /var/tmp/myswap
```

(of course, be sure that `/var/tmp/` is not a tmpfs mounted filesystem, but sits on some disk, perhaps an SSD one....)

When you don't need any more a lot of swap space, run `swapoff /var/tmp/myswap`....

You could also start some external shell process near the beginning of your program (à la `popen`) and later you might send shell commands to it. Look at my [execicar.c](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/execicar.c) program for inspiration, or use it if it fits (I wrote it 10 years ago for similar purposes, but I forgot the details)

Alternatively fork at the beginning of your program some interpreter ([Lua](http://lua.org/), [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/)...) and send some commands to it.

**Running more than a few dozens commands per second**  (starting any external program) **is not reasonable**, and should be considered as a design mistake, IMHO. Perhaps the commands that you are running could be replaced by in-process functions (e.g. `/bin/ls` can be done with `stat`, `readdir`, `glob` *functions* ...). Perhaps you might consider **adding some [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plugins) ability** (with [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) & `dlsym`) to your code (and run functions from plugins instead of starting very often the same programs). Or perhaps **embed an interpreter** (Lua, Guile, ...) inside your code.

<sup>As an example, for web servers, look for old [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) vs [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) or HTTP forwarding (e.g. [URL redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection)) or embedded [PHP](http://php.net/) or [HOP](http://hop.inria.fr/) or [Ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/)</sup>

Comment: In the post, Let_Me_Be think when you fork in a 4-8GB program, this program will use 4-8GB * 2 memory

Comment: @LouisMartin-Pierrat No, it won't use the memory, but the fork will fail unless you have space for the copy.

Comment: The fork might fail if you don't have enough swap space. That is not a big deal, add some more swap space. I am telling how.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Well, that still doesn't address my actual problem.

Comment: Okay I understand, the fork fail if you don't have 4-8GB * 2 memory available. And I think use swap like that is not the "best" option to resolve his problem

Answer (score 2):

> This makes fork-exec cumbersome, as the fork itself can take
>   significant time

This is only half true. You didn't specify the OS, but `fork(2)` is pretty optimized in Linux (and I believe in other UNIX variants) by using copy-on-write. Copy-on-write means that the operating system will not copy the entire parent memory address space until the child (or the parent) writes to memory. So you can rest assured that if you have a parent process using 8 GB of memory and then you fork, you won't be using 16 GB of memory - *especially* if the child execs() something immediately.

> fork will fail unless there is enough memory for a copy of the entire
>   resident memory.

No. The only overhead incurred by `fork(2)` is the copy and allocation of a task structure for the child, the allocation of a PID, and copying the parent's page tables. `fork(2)` will *not* fail if there isn't enough memory to copy the entire parent's address space, it will fail if there isn't enough memory to allocate a new task structure and the page tables. It may also fail if the maximum number of processes for the user has been reached. You can confirm this in `man 2 fork` (NOTE: See comments below).

If you still don't want to use `fork(2)`, you can use `vfork(2)`, which does no copying at all - it doesn't even copy the page tables - everything is shared with the parent. You can use that to create a new child process with a negligible overhead and then exec() something. Be aware that `vfork(2)` blocks the calling thread until the child either exits or calls one of the seven exec() functions. You also shouldn't modify the memory inside the child process before calling any of the exec() functions.

Comment: Can you call vfork in a thread ? (to avoid this part : vfork(2) blocks on the parent until the child either exits or calls one of the seven exec() functions) using a worker pool to launch exec + vfork could be a good idea if you can use thread to launch vfork

Comment: @LouisMartin-Pierrat Yes, you can. In fact, technically I should have said *`vfork(2)` blocks the calling thread until the child exits or calls exec()*.

Comment: @LouisMartin-Pierrat Yeah, sure. Any thread can fork a new process.

Comment: @LouisMartin-Pierrat If the new processes call exec(), you're all good, but if they don't, note that the new processes only have one thread each, and it may be hard, if not impossible, to get them to a consistent state. For example, locks may be acquired in the parent at the time of the fork, and the child process inherits those locks, but not their threads, so there is no way it can recover or otherwise get them into a consistent state. There are ways around this, but if you're just forking to exec(), this doesn't matter. Just keep it in mind if you later change the design.

Comment: You are definitely not right with the second part of you answer. I have experienced `fork()` failing on a 4GB process with 3.5GB free memory.

Comment: Okay I see, it's just theorical for me because I don't need that actually. I was just thinking about my previous work.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be If that was in Linux, I'm pretty sure it wasn't because of memory. `fork(2)` is implemented with `clone(2)`, and `clone(2)` is generic enough in that it will not fail under such circumstances. Fork itself will not fail, but if the child starts writing to all of the 4 GB of memory, the OOM killer may kick in and kill it, but I'm pretty sure `fork(2)` won't fail in the scenario you described. I'm not sure about other operating systems - this is valid for Linux only.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves This was on Linux. It might be a quirk of some older kernel version (we are using pretty old kernels), but fork did definitely fail in this circumstance.

Comment: `fork` can fail when the operating system doesn't allow overcommit. In many Unix-like systems, including Linux, this is configurable with many systems disabling overcommit by default. This means that `fork` can fail because even though you're not using the copy-on-write memory, you still reserve it and without overcommit you can't reserve more than there is. Certain flavors of linux (Centos comes to mind) have a default limit on overcommit so that you can't reserve more than 150% of your memory.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Fair enough. That must be it then.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you can `fork`+`exec` 10k times per second. That sounds very excessive. Have you considered making the things you're `exec`ing into a daemon? Or maybe implement those external programs inside your application? It sounds very dodgy to have to fork that much.

`fork` most likely starts failing for you despite having the memory to back it because you're on a flavor of linux that has disabled (or put a limit on) memory overcommit. Check the file `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`. If it's 1 then my guess is wrong and there's something else weird going on. If it's 0 then you're not allowed to overcommit at all. If it's 2 then you need to read the documentation for how exactly this gets configured.

One solution mentioned above is just adding swap (that will never get used).

Another solution is to implement a small daemon that will take commands and execute those forks and execs for you piping back whatever output you need.

N.B. `fork` of a large process can in theory be as fast as a small process. The performance of fork is determined by how many memory mappings you have rather than how much memory they cover. Setting up copy-on-write is done per mapping. Except that on certain operating systems setting up COW of anonymous mappings is linear to amount of memory in those mappings, but I don't know what Linux does here, last time I studied the VM system in Linux was over 15 years ago.